# How to use bootstrap when sending a mail with html body in ios, objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, twitter-bootstrap, email

I working with a `web service` that can send `email`.

As the **message body** I want to send it as **html** body. I can send html **body with style**. but I want to use bootstrap and `jquery` with it. I just want to know, is it possible, if it is possible, how can I do that.

this is how I use it now.

```
NSString *thebody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n<head> \n <title></title> \n </head>\n <body> \n <h1 style='background-color:orange;'>Flight Summary</h1>  \n</body> \n</html>"];

            [self sendmailwhenbookinSuccess:@"this is test mail" :@"billfox@bokings.co.uk" :@"this is a test mail" :thebody]; // this is the web service method.
```

this works fine , and can send mails properly.

but now I want to use it with `bootstrap` and `jquery` like below :

```
NSString *thejquery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"];




NSString *thebody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n<head> \n <title></title> \n <script src='%@'></script> \n <script src='%@'></script> \n </head>\n <body> \n <h1 style='background-color:orange;'>Flight Summary</h1>  \n</body> \n</html>",thejquery];

    [self sendmailwhenbookinSuccess:@"this is test mail" :@"billfox@bookings.co.uk" :@"this is a test mail" :thebody];
```

if this is possible, how can I do this.